# Azure connect successfully , I get correct JSON result when doing CRUD but then no Response , no Error Message And stop Working

Tags: android, asp.net, azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-android-sdk

I am using **Azure Mobile service developing Android application** ,
I set the connection up successfully ,
and make sure that the **Action to Backend** will send **Correct JSON back**.
But When I call

```
myUserTable.execute().get();
```

first , I get a response in my log which contents **correct JSON** from ServiceFilter

but after then it stop working without any **Error Message** and **Exception** ...

it just stop further working ...

please see my codes below :

**for the CRUD operation function :**

```
private void initiate() {
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try{
                            Link_Azure azure = null;
                            Log.d("myLog","Start Binding database");
                            azure = Link_Azure.bindWithMainActivity(MainActivity.this);
                            List<User> us= azure.loadUserFromTable();
                            Log.d("myLog","User id : "+us.size());
                        }catch(MalformedURLException | MobileServiceException | InterruptedException | ExecutionException err){
                            err.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
    runAsyncTask(task);
}
```

It turns out not reach **Log.d("myLog","User id : "+us.size());**

**Function for initiate Azure Setting**

```
public static Link_Azure bindWithMainActivity(Context main) throws MalformedURLException {
    if (azureInstance == null)
        azureInstance = new Link_Azure(main);
    return azureInstance;
}

private Link_Azure(Context main) throws MalformedURLException {
    this.context = main;
    mClient = new MobileServiceClient(LINK,context).withFilter(new ProgressFilter());
    mClient.setAndroidHttpClientFactory(new OkHttpClientFactory() {
        @Override
        public OkHttpClient createOkHttpClient() {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            client.setReadTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            client.setWriteTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            return client;
        }
    });
    initiateTables();
}

private void initiateTables(){
    mUserManager = mClient.getTable("User",User.class);
    mProduct = mClient.getTable("Product",ProductImp.class);
    mMail = mClient.getTable("Mail",Mail.class);
    mLockerImp = mClient.getTable("Locker",LockerImp.class);
}
```

**for Query operation**

```
public List<User> loadUserFromTable() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException, MobileServiceException {
    return mUserManager.execute().get();
}
```

**And here are all Tables in our Database :**

[image]

verbose Log:

```
03-08 07:25:46.467 9662-9662/com.example.androidwork.foodsharing W/art: Verification of void     com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.table.sync.MobileServiceSyncContext.processOperation(com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.table.sync.operations.TableOperation, com.google.gson.JsonObject) took 218.338ms
03-08 07:25:46.542 9662-9756/com.example.androidwork.foodsharing W/ResourcesManager: Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
03-08 07:25:46.542 9662-9756/com.example.androidwork.foodsharing W/ResourcesManager: Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
03-08 07:25:47.227 9662-9759/com.example.androidwork.foodsharing D/myLog: [{"deleted":false,"updatedAt":"2017-03-06T15:13:47.927Z","createdAt":"2017-03-05T10:52:24.031Z","version":"AAAAAAAAC78=","id":"32C63DBF-F531-4ED9-ABF2-D83919C5F7E7","password":"123","account":"1235","email":null,"phone":null,"live":null,"age":15,"name":"水球潘管理員"}]
```

Comment: If you do a Fiddler or Postman request, does it produce the right results?  If you turn on Diagnostic Logging at the verbose level and then use the log stream, are any errors produced?

Comment: Yes ,  It seems correct on Postman ,  I used it to delete and query with a correct result like it shows on Android ORZ ... and I checked out the verbose log , it ends up with the line contents JSON Response ( I have updated my question ) , thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem , 
the point is , the operation on MobileServiceTable
must run on the **Non-UI thread**

So that means

```
public List<User> loadUserFromTable() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException, MobileServiceException {
return mUserManager.execute().get();
```

}

is wrong , I should create another Thread to do the request.